# Memory leak in ASP.NET Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have two similar methods in a class that return null.  Only difference is the method arguments they accept.

In both cases, the class that contains the below method implementation is added to the services collection in Startup class using `services.AddScoped<MyClass>();` . The container is responsible to create the instance of the class and also dispose the object accordingly.

App starts with 90MB without any initial request (Diagnostics tool to monitor).

Method-1 : No memory leak for 150 calls/minute. (Grows to 250MB for the first request and stays there for the rest of the time.)

```
public Task<MyObject> DoNothing()
{
   return null;
}
```

Method-2 : Memory creeps up and reaches 800 MB for 150 calls/minute.  Even after waiting for long, the memory usage is still around 750MB.

```
public Task<MyObject> DoSomething(string args1,.....,string args10)
{
    return null;
}
```

Based on my analysis, it seems to be the arguments that are passed to Method-2 are not getting disposed and hence the memory leak. I cannot change the signature of Method-2 due to existing interface restrictions. The total size of the arguments being passed to Method-2 is around 1.25MB for each request.

I have also implemented IDisposable and Finalizer method and the override Dispose method (nothing in here at the moment) is called everytime. This ensures the object is being cleaned-up after each request.

So my question and the help I am looking for is, how do I make sure the HttpRequest that contains the list of arguments to Method-2 are disposed and how do I fix this memory leak issue?

Please find the source code along with the SOAP UI xml config file for test and load testing ***[here](https://github.com/bluedog13/core-wcf-soap)***

Comment: Are the arguments all strings or is that for the sake of your example?

Comment: There are around 8 strings, 3 boolean, an enum and one object array in the arguments list.

Comment: Have you tried disposing them (setting to null) in the method before `return null;`?

Comment: I did try after your suggestion. I could not set the 3 boolean/enum fields to null, but for the rest (string/objects), I was able to and saw no difference in the memory behaviour. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: How do you register your class? Can be the problem be in the difference between services.AddScoped(new Instance()) and services.AddScoped(provider => new Instance()) ?

Comment: In Startup.cs: `services.AddScoped<MyClass>();` which is the only class that contains both the methods with different memory performance. I leave it upto the container to create an instance, because this way it is responsible to create the instance and also clean up the instance.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? It's not really clear how `MyClass` is relevant here

Comment: `MyClass` plays a smaller role because it gets created for each request during the load testing. But on more investigation, I found that, one of the input to the method that is 800KB long, if this is passed as empty, then the memory leak does not happen.  So this comes to a string input parameter that is 800 KB long causing the memory spike.

Comment: @GautamTGoudar I've tried to reproduce your issue according to the given description but I didn't see any memory leaks. In both cases the memory consumption was about 10MB. You can check the [source code](https://pastebin.com/6mZnccB7) of my test and use it to create your own sample which reproduces this issue for 100%

Comment: I have posted the link to the source code along with the Soap UI xml config file in the original post.  So when you run the project, it will start on http://localhost:16407/Service.svc. Use the Soap load test to run (1) DoNothing (2)DoSomething_NoBigString and (3) DoSomething_BigString_1 to see the memory behaviour

Comment: This problem is mostly related to LOH (Large Object Heap) and how GC works in respect to LOH.

Comment: @GautamTGoudar did you ever work this out?

Comment: Not really. You can force GC and tweak a bit to see some difference but it does not solve the issue in total. NET has some optimizations (4.7.1 onwards or .Net Standard 2.0) but essentially LOH is an issue.  A better way to fix such issues is to change the design of the application.